# Replacing the HandLandmarker model that they use in mediapipe

Tags: python, mediapipe

How can I replace the HandLandmarker model that they use in mediapipe framework? I want to try to re train the model and just fool around with it and see if I can train it better myself using my local machine.[I want to replace this model with something else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXLlQ.png)

Comment: You may read more about this model pair: [Model card](https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-assets/Model%20Card%20Hand%20Tracking%20(Lite_Full)%20with%20Fairness%20Oct%202021.pdf); [https://blog.research.google/2019/08/on-device-real-time-hand-tracking-with.html](https://blog.research.google/2019/08/on-device-real-time-hand-tracking-with.html); and make your question more concrete.